# app crashes on simulator 8 but not on device

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I updated Xcode to version 6 and changed the deployment target for my iOS application to 8.1 from the previous 7.0. Before this update, the application ran without any issues on my iPad and on the iOS simulator. After the update however, I can run the application as before on my device (previously iOS 7 but also just updated to iOS 8.1) but it crashes on the simulator with a NSInvalidArgumentException:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell disclosureButton]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f85c7f0'
```

There's nothing special about BuildingCell or the disclosureButton for that matter. But the app crashes when I attempt to add an action to the disclosure button.

The BuildingCell header:

```
@interface BuildingsCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *disclosureButton;

@end
```

Function where the application crashes:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BuildingCell";
    BuildingsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [BuildingsCell.alloc initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    //*** App crashes on the line below ***
    [cell.disclosureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedCell:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    Building *currentBuilding = self.buildingArray[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Function I attempt to link to the disclosureButton

```
- (void) tappedCell:(id)sender
{
   CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.buildingTableView];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.buildingTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

  [self tableView:self.buildingTableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

I can't find anything wrong with the code. Is it possible that there's an issue with the simulator? Does the simulator have parameters that I need to set? I haven't done much with Xcode or this application in a while and I'm clearly missing something. Any suggestions would be helpful at this point as I'm out of idea.

Comment: Dont' you need `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` for the `accessoryType` in the line above the one where it crashes? Perhaps I'm wrong or missing something though.

Comment: I was just going to say the same thing as lewiguez. I think you're trying to add an event to an item that doesn't exist. Try changing the line above the crash to cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

Comment: Also, just to be clear, you have cell = BuildingsCell.alloc for your alloc/init pair. Line 7. Not sure if that is a typo or not. I'm assuming yet, but just wanted to point it out in case.

Comment: `BuildingsCell *cell = (BuildingsCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`?

Comment: I tried changing the cell.accessoryType to UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton but the app crashes just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Wow . . . So I discovered the problem in my application. It was nowhere near what I was expecting.

The issue was actually one of localization. My application is in French, but i have an incomplete English storyboard (an earlier attempt the make the app bilingual) which was put to rest on the back burner a long while back. So despite the fact that I was setting the language of the simulator to french, every time the application ran on the simulator it was using the incomplete english storyboard. I failed to notice as, due to the crash, no more than the initial view (which contains no language distinguishing information) was visible.

It looks like Xcode 6 has made some localization updates.

I resolved the issue by setting the Application Language to "French" in the Edit Scheme.

So ya . . feeling a little sheepish now.

Thanks for the suggestions though.